# How to make an AJAX call so that it only fires when I click on a link contained within a specific class, and includes the "id" of the parent element?

Tags: javascript, ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I have the following on a web page:

```
<td class="containslink" id=1>
    <a href=/ControllerX/ActionY/7>View</a>
</td>
```

There are many versions of the above, each with a different id.

When the included link is clicked, I need the page to fire an AJAX call to the following address:

```
/Controller/Action/1
```

or

```
@Url.Action("Action", "Controller" new { id = 1 })
```

Where `id` is equal to the `td`'s id.

---

If I hardcode my AJAX call like this:

```
myUrl = @Url.Action("Action", "Controller" new { id = 1});

$(document).ready(function () {
    $("a").click(function(){
        $.ajax({
            url: myUrl,
        });
    });
});
```

The AJAX call fires when I click any link on the page and always fires with the `id` of 1 (obviously).

How would I change this AJAX call so that it only works when I click on a link contained within a `td class` of `"containsLink"`, and includes the `id` of the `td` that contains the link that was clicked?

Comment: How you getting your TD id? why couldn't dynamically build your link with TD id, similar like this <a href=@Url.Content("/Controller/Action" + Id + ")>View</a>?

Comment: Because I have many of these on the page - the AJAX needs to be able to read the data from the specific link that was clicked.  -- unless I am unaware of exactly what you're getting at.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'd need to tighten your selector (don't just select all `<a>` elements) and get the ID in the event handler.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("td.containslink a").click(function(){
        var id = $(this).closest("td.containslink").attr("id");
        $.ajax({
            url: "/Controller/Action/" + id
        });
    });
});
```

Note that `1` is an invalid ID as it starts with a number. You might want to use `data-` attributes instead, like `data-id`.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("td.containsLink > a").click(function(){
        var tdId = $(this).parent("td.containsLink").attr("id");
        // do what ever you need to do with td value here
        $.ajax({
            url: myUrl,
        });
    });
});
```